# cv::imread seems to leave file open on Windows, OpenCV Version 2.4

Tags: c++, opencv, imread

I suspect, cv::imread in v2.4 on windows doesn't close the file handle. I don't have the sources currently but this is what I'm observed:

My app loads many images. The release version at customer's PC was deadlocked exactly after the same number of images. This never happened, then I started the process from VisualStudio, neither in debug nor in release modes.
Using the logging I've identified, that the deadlock happend near cv::imread call. I've replaced the cv::imread call by reading in QImage (Qt4.8) and converted the data from QImage to cv::Mat. And the error disappeared.

I think, this has something to do with the max number of open handles parameter of Windows. Could someone confirm?

Comment: There were at least 13 releases in the 2.4 branch -- could you, perhaps, be a little more specific? | BTW, all the source code is on [github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv).

Comment: @DanMašek Ok, thank you for the hint. I've visited the code but couldn't identify any missing fclose (internally opencv is C not C++ ??? ). I'll try to update my libraries.